# Почему скрипт на Питоне не понимает юникод?

Tags: python, python-2.x, unicode

Скрипт:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    
print "Привет"
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "./y.sh", line 2  
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file ./y.sh on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы сказать интерпретатору о наличии юникода?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Нужно добавить в начало специальный комментарий.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Привет"
```

Comment: Надо просто перейти на третий питон, а не гонять Му-му со вторым.

Comment: @Sergey Ага, в 2010 году, когда он только пару лет как появился и все ещё сидели на 2-м, ну конечно. Вопрос то 2010 года.

Answer (score 7):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    
print u"Привет"
```

Comment: Ответ неправильный. В python 2 при использовании кириллицы и без указания кодировки в начале файла гарантированно будет ошибка. Простая замена обычных строк на юникодные тут не поможет.